# What does the gain of a non inverting OpAmp depend on?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I know that it does not depend on the output impedance of the voltage source, but can it depend on the input impedance of the amplifier?

Comment: depends on both. Your answer is here. See the analysis of gain : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/374041/what-is-the-closed-loop-gain-in-this-op-amp-circuit/374085#374085

Comment: It depends on the divider network on the feedback