# How to solve practical OPAMP with finite differential resistance and finite offset current while other parameters can be considered ideal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, bias, negative-feedback, input-offset-voltage

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fte16j.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ip(bias)=200nA
rd=differential resistance=5Mohm
a=infinite
What should be its output?
I am confused if I should consider negative feedback and consider bias current gives only input offset voltage of straightway say that OPAMP is saturated.

Comment: Assume Vin- = Vin+ =0  (ignore  Ip*100=20uV)  and Vout drives Vin  to that voltage, so what is Vout ... Note  R's are equal

Comment: How can I ignore 1V (200nA*5M=1V)

Comment: So in a nutshell, in ideal case when input bias current \$I_b = 0\$ and also input impedance \$Z_{in} = \infty\$, you understand that the \$V_{out} = V_{in} = -1V\$. What do you want to ask that how to derive the value of \$V_{out}\$ if \$I_b \ne 0\$ and \$Z_{in} \ne \infty\$ right?

Comment: @Unknown123 right

Comment: You add additional voltage sources to the schematic, with the new voltages being the error voltages. You may need to perform Norton to Thevenin conversions.

Comment: Already got the answer? May be worth to check this question if you haven't. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/374041/what-is-the-closed-loop-gain-in-this-op-amp-circuit